# What is the best way to allow third-party changes to Runtime Shared Libraries?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, shared-libraries, custom-component

How can I do the following in Flex 4.5 or later:

1. Compile an swc library file containing packages of simple functions
2. Compile an swf application referencing the swc file as RSL
3. Publish the swf application
4. Send the source code of the swc file to another developer
5. Allow the developer to modify the code of some functions while keeping their interfaces
6. Allow the developer to compile the source code into a new swc file using only compc
7. Allow the developer to replace my original swc file with his new swc file, then execute my swf application having the new swc file in the same directory.

I tried the above many times, just to fail. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to eliminate additional compilation against the updated libraries is re-thinking your architecture: If all the dependencies in the RSL are [properly decoupled](http://www.actionscript-flash-guru.com/blog/7-decouple-externally-loaded-swfs-in-as3), you should not have any problems.